# JSON not returned from yarn REST API

Tags: json, rest, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm calling the yarn REST API in order to discover information about jobs.I can hit http://server:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps in Postman and get a list of applications in JSON:
[image]

Great. I now want to get information about each individual application. According to  [Hadoop YARN - Introduction to the web services REST API's](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebServicesIntro.html) the call is:
[image]

but when I try pasting that URL (well, the equivalent for my server & application) into my browser I'm sent to this:
[image]

I wanted a JSON document as per the docs above but I'm not getting it.

As per the docs I try using curl but get nothing:
[image]

Tried using PowerShell instead:

[image]

As you can see it returned HTML, not JSON. To confirm, here's the same in Postman:
[image]
[image]

Here's information about the cluster via a call to http://server:8088/ws/v1/cluster 
[image]

I need it to return JSON. Any suggestions? TIA.

Answer (score 5):

If the application is in a **FINISHED** state, you will need to send your request to the **history server** in order to get a JSON response, otherwise you will get an HTML response. If the application is in a **RUNNING** state, you need to send your request directly to the MapReduce application master that is running.

Getting list of jobs for an application in **FINISHED** state:

```
curl --compressed -X GET "http://host.domain.com:19888/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs"
```

Getting list of jobs for an application in **RUNNING** state:

```
curl --compressed -X GET "http://host.domain.com:8088/proxy/{app_id}/ws/v1/mapreduce/jobs"
```

The default port for the history server is **19888** and the endpoint is */ws/v1/history*

References:
[Intro to YARN REST APIs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebServicesIntro.html)
[YARN History Server Rest API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HistoryServerRest.html)